# Extract selected data from a .csv file to another

Tags: batch-file, csv

I need to know if it's possible to create a batch .bat file to extract from a .csv several rows and save these selected rows into another .csv file. I have read another topics on this webpage and i can only find how to split my csv in several files cutting it by a defined number of rows (for example cutting it in csv files of 500 rows max.).

In the csv files which i would like to manage there are several rows of data with the same structure.

I want to extract into another .csv file some rows of these filtering by a ticket number which is located in each row at a certain position. I don't want to make any change at the original file where the files will be exported, I only want to copy these files into another .csv. For example if i have these rows:

```
19/09/2013 123456789
19/09/2013 231564215
19/09/2013 456464231
19/09/2013 564659832
19/09/2013 000000054
```

As is shown, the ticket numbers is located always between the 12th and the 21st position. In this example i want to extract to another csv file the rows with the ticket numbers "231564215" and "564659832". So the data inside the new .csv file must be:

```
19/09/2013 231564215
19/09/2013 564659832
```

I need the script to ask you for the name of the original file from where you want to extract and save the data, and obviously to ask you for the number of the tickets you would like to extract (separated by carriage returns for example). The sequence i will like to get is something like this:

```
CMD Says: Please select the file you would like to convert
I type: c:/Documents and setting/Marta/testFile.csv
CMD Says: Please enter the list of tickets you want to export
I type: 231564215
564659832
CMD Says: Exporting data...
CMD: Export process finished. Your new file is c:/Documents and setting/Marta/exportedData.csv
```

NB: Sorry for my poor English, I'm Spanish

Comment: 1) I can't see a `CSV` file 2) what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**edited**

Based upon the sample files you provided, the required numbers cannot be mixed up with any other portion of each record so this returns the data you need:

```
@echo off
( for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("Ticket Numbers.txt") do find ",%%a," <"originalFile.csv"  )>"newfile.csv"
```

Is that a useful way of getting the data into a new file?

Comment: This will give false matches to lines that have the number embedded within a larger number. You probably want `"\<231564215$ \<564659832$"` so that it only matches whole "words".

Comment: Yes, @dbenham - I suspect the input data is nothing like what was posted, so I just replied based on the posted data and will wait to see if the OP replies.

Comment: Thank all oy you guys. I can attach if you want the orginal .csv and a manual-made file just equals what i want for the output of the bath but how can i attach files here?

Comment: Sites like http://pastebin.com/ will allow you to post some data, or use another hosting site (one that doesn't require registration).

Comment: Hello foxidrive,

I have just uploaded the files to putlocker.

http://www.putlocker.com/file/95293AD5D08F8458
http://www.putlocker.com/file/E05473F4BF50CF59
http://www.putlocker.com/file/6345B6645A53AAFE
http://www.putlocker.com/file/AA38AFF0A47F7BFA


I have uploaded the original csv file from where i have to extract the data.
An example of the output file which i want to get with the batch execution.
The .txt to indicate to the batch file which tickets i want to extract.
And a txt where i explain the process.

Many many thanks for your interest.

Best regards,
Marta Arcones